# wpdb->insert adds too many rows

Tags: theme-development, database, wpdb

I have the following code in my `functions.php`

```
$ar = array(
    'price_content' => 'hello'
    );

$result = $wpdb->insert('hs_prices', $ar); // insert 'hello' into 'price_content'
```

This should just create one row, but it creates 12 in the database. I am on the homepage of the website when I run this (by refreshing the page).

Could this be because the code is in `functions.php`, and it's being included 12 or so times throughout the site?

**edit:** It shouldn't be because it's in `functions.php`, as it also does it when on `index.php`. Must be the query.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Did you add the code snippet into the global scope of `functions.php` or inside some action/filter ?

Comment: Global scope. Should it be linked with a filter?

Answer (score 0):

This works if add this code in `functions.php`?

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'test_setup' ) ) :

function test_setup() {

    $ar = array(
    'price_content' => 'hello'
    );

$result = $wpdb->insert('hs_prices', $ar); // insert 'hello' into 'price_content'

}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'test_setup' );
```

Comment: Please add a proper explanation to how your code works and why it should work. Don't just dump code and says it works.